# Python Caesar Cipher Program With No Key

Tags: python

I would like some help with figuring out the shift in a caesar cipher program, when no shift has been specified.

My current program:

```
def Decode():
    ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    data = []
    string = input("Please enter the string you wish to decode.\n") 
    shift = int(input("Enter the key. (Number of shifts used when encoding original word.)\n"))
    for i in string:
        if i.strip() and i in ALPHABET: 
            data.append(ALPHABET[(ALPHABET.index(i) - shift) % 26]) 
        else:
            data.append(i)
    output = ''.join(data)
    return (output)
```

How can I turn this program into one that  prompts for a string to decode and a plain-text word that appears in the text (decoded string) and uses them to figure out the key in the caesar cipher shift?

For example: If the encoded string is: khoor zruog and the plain-text word is: hello, The program should work out the rotation was 3 and the decoded string is 'hello world'

This must be done without the ord or char functions.

Comment: Brute force (try them all), maybe. There are only 26 variations.

Comment: Write a function that does the shift `shift(text, number)`.  Then iterate through `for i in range(26)`, calling `shift` with `i` as `number` for each.  Then you can just check `word in shift(text, i)` for each to see which keys have your word in the output.  The other option would be frequency analysis to guess which letters are which based on which are the most common in english.